# Understanding git commit --only and pre-commit hooks

Tags: git, githooks, jetbrains-ide

I'm working on a pre-commit hook to reformat code, and in general, it works; it reformats and `git add`s any staged files, and the resulting commit contains the reformatted code as desired.

However, it doesn't play nicely with `git commit --only` (which is the variant used by JetBrains IDEs), and I'm trying to understand why. The combination of `git commit --only` and the pre-commit hook results in an undesirable index/working tree state, as described in the following sequence of events:

If I make a small change with a formatting error to a file and then run `git status`, this is what I see:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   file.php

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

If I then commit using `git commit --only -- file.php`, the pre-commit hook runs, and the changed and reformatted `file.php` is committed.

However, if I then run `git status` again, this is the result (arrow annotations mine):

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   file.php <-- contains original change, improperly formatted

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   file.php <-- contains original change, properly formatted (per the most recent commit)
```

Where are the new staged change and the change in the working tree coming from?

Can someone explain exactly how `git commit --only` interacts with the index to produce the result shown above — and even better, whether there's a way to have my pre-commit hook play nicely with it?

My understanding is that `git commit --only` works with the version of the file in the working tree, so I tried removing the `git add` step from the pre-commit hook to see what would happen, and it resulted in the improperly-formatted version of the file being committed and the properly-formatted one in the working tree (which matches my expectations for a standard `git commit`, but I wasn't sure what to expect in the context of `git commit --only`).

I'm aware of the possibility of using a `clean` filter to reformat the code, rather than a pre-commit hook, but there are a few situational complications introduced by that approach that would be nice to avoid if possible.

**Note:** This question is related to [Phpstorm and pre commit hooks that modify files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931103/phpstorm-and-pre-commit-hooks-that-modify-files) but is focused on addressing the problem in the context of `git commit --only`. Moreover, the problem doesn't seem to have been addressed by JetBrains, as was suggested in the accepted answer to that question.

Comment: On more about pre-commit influence on git commit behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7230886/6309

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The precise details vary from one version of Git to another, and some people—I'm not saying the JetBrains folks are among them, as I have no idea—have tried to bypass the way Git does things and in the process, screwed things up such that either they can't be worked-around, or the work-around is Git-version-dependent.  However, the main idea in these Git hooks is all the same:

- the *index* contains the commit-to-make, and
- the *work-tree* contains the work-tree.

These two need not be in sync when you first run `git commit`, and if you add files to the `git commit` command, with either `--only` or `--include`, Git must then make a *new* index, which may differ from the regular ordinary index.  So now we wind up with an environment variable, `GIT_INDEX_FILE`, set to the path of a new, temporary index.<sup>1</sup>  Since all Git commands automatically respect the environment variables, the pre-commit hook will use the temporary index's files, and `git write-tree` will use the temporary index's files.

Of course, anything that *fails* to respect the temporary index—or, potentially, depending on `--include` vs `--only`, just uses the contents of the work-tree—will get the wrong answer.

There is still a problem, though, even with programs that *do* respect the environment variables.  Suppose we have a file—let's call it `test` since that's its purpose—that initially contains "headvers", and matches the current (`HEAD`) commit.  Now we modify it in the work-tree to contain "indexvers" and run `git add test`.  The index version of `test` thus reads "indexvers".  Now we modify it *again* in the work-tree, to contain "workvers", and run either `git commit --only test` or `git commit --include test`.

We know for sure what should go into the new commit: it should be the version of test containing `workvers`, because we specifically told Git to commit the work-tree version.  But what should be left in the index and work-tree *afterward*?  Does this depend on whether we used `--include` vs `--only`?  I don't know what to consider the "right" answer here!  All I can tell you is that when I experimented with Git before, it tended to contain `workvers` afterward (both in the index, and in the work-tree).  That is, the temporary index's version became the normal index's version, and the work-tree file was untouched.

(If you have Git hooks that manipulate the index and/or work-tree, you will be able to pry open the difference between "copying index to saved-index, then copying back" vs "copying index to temp-index, then using temp-index".)

---

<sup>1</sup>This was the actual implementation at one time, when I was testing various behaviors, but it's possible that the actual implementation has changed a bit.  For instance, Git could save the "normal" index in a temporary file and then replace the normal index, so that `GIT_INDEX_FILE` is *not* set after all.  And, again, it may depend on `--include` vs `--only`.

Note that `git commit -a` may also use a temporary index, or not.  I believe this behavior has changed between Git 1.7 and Git 2.10, based on the result of running `git status` in another window while still editing the commit message in the window that was running `git commit -a`.

Answer (score 4):

I came across the same problem. Here is the solution I got from a Jetbrains dev Dmitriy Smirnov.

---

`git commit --only` is used due to several reasons:

1. Git stage is not supported - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63391
2. It allows doing partial commits - committing individual files. this is crucial to support change lists in the IDE.

It is not possible to change the behavior at the moment.

Given the pre-commit hook as follows (ruby):

```
`git status --porcelain`.lines do |line|
    changed_file = line.split(' ', 2)[1].strip()
    if (File.extname(changed_file).downcase() == '.java')
        system "java -jar bin/google-java-format-1.4-all-deps.jar --aosp --replace #{changed_file}"
        system "git add #{changed_file}"
    end
end
```

Add a `post-commit` hook:

```
git update-index -g
```

See

> https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-81139#comment=27-295117